# PHP mkdir issue!

Tags: php, permissions, file-permissions, mkdir

I trying to create some dirs like this:

```
@mkdir("photos/$cat/$sku", 0777, true)
```

it creates the first directory with 0777 permissions, but when it creates the second is uses 000 as it's perms, so it fails to create the third.

A workaround this please?

Thanks,
Richard.

Comment: have you tried creating them directories one at a time?

Comment: pardon my ignorance, but what's the @ symbol for? also, the script worked for me ... maybe something else is afoot.

Comment: doesn't work either. just tried. Creates the first but happens the same on the second and third.

Comment: @ is to remove error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved the issue:

```
$a = @mkdir("photos/$cat/", 0777);
    @chmod("photos/$cat/", 0777);
    $b = @mkdir("photos/$cat/$sku/", 0777);
    @chmod("photos/$cat/$sku/", 0777);
```

but why can't use recursive on mkdir?

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it works perfect:

```
    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        $dirs = explode('/', $path);
        $i = 0;
        $subdir = '';
        foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
            if($i > 0){$dir = '/' . $dir;}
            $subdir .= $dir;
            if(!is_dir(DIR_CACHE . $subdir)){@mkdir(DIR_CACHE . $subdir);@chmod(DIR_CACHE . $subdir, 0777);}

            $i++;
        }
    }
```

So all you have to do is define your path ( $path = photos/$cat/$sku )

Answer (score 0):

dear it is due to user rights, please check the user when you are creating the any dir using mkdir function,

Comment: but it creates the first, why not the rest?

Comment: r u creating the sub dir's within first created directory??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `chmod`ing the directories?

```
mkdir("photos/$cat", 0777, true);
chmod("photos", 0777);
chmod("photos/$cat", 0777);
mkdir("photos/$cat/$sku", 0777);
chmod("photos/$cat/$sku", 0777);
```